# How to send HTTP-Request from my IntegrationFlow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I receive a Request from the Client which returns a SendRequest-Object that has a HttpMethod, a path and data to send.
Now I would like to send the Request depending on the object I get to the API.

After sending I will get a Response.

The problem now is how can I send the payload and receive the response.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpPostSendRawData() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Http.inboundGateway("/api/data/send")
                        .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                        .statusCodeExpression(dataParser().parseExpression("T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).BAD_REQUEST"))
                        .requestPayloadType(ResolvableType.forClass(DataSend.class))
                        .crossOrigin(cors -> cors.origin("*"))
                        .headerMapper(dataHeaderMapper())
        )
                .channel("http.data.send.channel")
                .handle("rawDataEndpoint", "send")
                .transform(/* here i have some transformations*/)
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway((Message<SendRequest> r)->r.getPayload().getPath())
                        .httpMethod(/* Here I would like to get the Method of SendRequest*/)
                        //add payload
                        .extractPayload(true))
.get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what is your `SendRequest`, but the idea for the `method` is exactly the same what you have done for the `url`:

```
.httpMethodFunction((Message<SendRequest> r)->r.getPayload().getMethod())
```

Although, since you want to have some extraction for the request body, you need to do that in advance in the `transform()` and move values for `url` and `method` to the headers.
There is just no any payload extraction in the `Http.outboundGateway`: it deals with the whole request payload as an entity for HTTP request body.

Comment: is it possible to let the expectedResponseType generic? Because different Paths may send different response data. It works first of all with a responseType String.class

Comment: Please, read API and its JavaDocs. There is a similar `expectedResponseTypeFunction()` to determine a type against request message.